# grails query on nested attributes without criteria builder

Tags: grails, nested, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

My grails app has the following classes

```
class Person {
    Address address
    // other attributes
}

class Address {
    String street
    City city
    // more attributes
}
```

I would like to query the first 5 people alphabetically by street name. Currently I do something like

```
def criteria = Person.createCriteria();
def people = criteria.list(max:5) {
    address {
       order("street","asc")
    }
}
```

This works. I'm just wondering if there's a shorter way to do this (possibly without the criteria builder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think this is the clearest and most efficient way of doing it.  You could try things like [executeQuery](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html), but to be honest, I'm not sure if that's any less verbose.  If you're just trying to shorten the code, you could simplify the first two lines:

```
def people = Person.createCriteria().list(max:5) {
...
```